# How to provide both initial data and subsequent events via WAMP/Websockets

Tags: websocket, synchronization, wamp, rpc, publish-subscribe

I have a an application from which I need to send live updates to web clients.

I'm currently happily using websockets for that, via the [WAMP](http://wamp.ws/) protocol, as it provides both **publish-subscribe** and **RPC** methods.

Now, I find that in lots of situations, when a user starts the application or a view, I need to send an initial state to the client, and then keep sending updates. I do the first with an RPC call, and the latter via publish-subscribe.

Now, this forces me to write server-side and client-side code for both of the methods, even while I'm basically conveying the same information in both cases.

On server side, I'm moving appropriate code to a common method, but I still need to take care of both sending the event and provide an entry point for the RPC call:

```
# RPC endpoint for getting mission info
def get_mission_info(self):
    return self.get_mission_info()

# Scheduled or manually called method to send mission info to all users
def publish_mission_info(self):
    self.wamp.publish("UPDATE_INFO", [self.get_mission_info()])

def get_mission_info(self):
    # Here we generate a JSON serializable dict with the info
    return info
```

And you canimagine, client side (JS or Python) shows a similar duplicity (two handler methods).

Question is: is there a more clever way of handling this, and avoiding that boilerplate code? Some approach I could follow, perhaps automatically sending last event of each type just to clients that ask for it, or that just subscribed? Perhaps something at crossbar level?

In general terms, I feel I could be doing a better state synchronization strategy leveraging these two channels (pub-sub and RPC). How does people do it?

My WAMP server is [Crossbar](http://crossbar.io/), and my client library is [autobahn.js](http://autobahn.ws) in Python and JS.

Comment: The getting of the initial state and the updating from a stream of updates which all (interested) clients receive are inherently two different actions. I don't see any way around that.

Comment: Had an idea: how about crossbar.io intercepting relevant events, saving the last instance of each of them, and then sending hat last copy of each event to clients as soon as they subscribe to the corresponding topic?

Comment: There is an issue for WAMP regarding this (https://github.com/wamp-proto/wamp-proto/issues/69), but even if implemented this would only work for your use case if each event contained the full state instead of state updates. (Full state = lots of unnecessary wire traffic)

Comment: This would work for me for several of my messages, but I feel it's not flexible enough and forces my client to deal with empty payloads. I'm however suggesting a different approach at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/crossbario/LbfbxnSd5YA .